# Node with ejs template files and angular causing double pages to appear

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, ejs

I am working on an application built with Nodejs (express), ejs, and Angular.
The backend will render a layout ejs template like so:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('layout', 'shared/layout');
```

and

```
    <div ui-view></div>
    <%- body %>
</body>
```

When a 404 error occurs, it is caught (by Node), and a 404 template is rendered instead:

```
if (req.xhr) {
    res.status(404).render('shared/404', { title: '404', message: 'Page not found' })
}
```

The problem is, that when you click a link on the 404 page, the new page is rendered, but the 404 page still 'lingers' at the bottom (2 pages shown at once).

Should this be handled by the frontend instead? Or is this a problem with the backend set up (and what are best practices here?), or do I need to force some kind of 'hard refresh' of the page when a link is clicked, so the 404 template goes away? I have tried using an Angular hard refresh: `<a ui-sref="state1" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">State 1</a>` but the backend just seems to inject `href="state1"` as well (I presume it does this before Angular takes over?)

Comment: Is there any reason you'd rather not just load the 404 template locally?

Comment: Do you have a `$stateProvider.state({....})`? That enables you set up your routes?

Comment: Yea, that is there, and it also seems to be telling the program to go to the 'home' state upon 404. Again though, the problem seems to be that the 404 is being caught by the node backend (which is then serving a different template), I cant quite see how this is supposed to 'piece together' with Angular

Comment: Why are you serving the 404 from the server? Why not on the client side?

Comment: No idea, I didn't make this site, just got on board with it, and trying to figure out what is going on and what the best way of doing it should be!

Comment: @dcodesmith have edited question slightly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114760/discussion-between-dcodesmith-and-timhc22).